# Are records guaranteed in Lambda events?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I'm writing a Lambda@Edge function and trying to figure out what the appropriate level of "defensiveness" is. I assume the `event` parameter is guaranteed, even `event.Records`, but is it guaranteed to be a non-empty array?

From an example in the AWS documentation:

```js
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    //Get contents of response
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response; // <- right here
    const headers = response.headers;

    // ...
```